# C++ delete[] on new char;

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
    char* str = new char; 
    str[0] = 'a'; 
    delete[] str; //Notice the []
}
```

It compiles, runs and nothing crashes (VC15 and g++)
It does however have 1 memory leak which I can clearly see with valgrind.

If I run the following code however:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
public:
    Foo(){
        std::cout << "Foo::Foo" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo(){
        std::cout << "Foo::~Foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{   
      Foo* foo = new Foo;
      delete[] foo;
      return 0;
}
```

I get an infinite loop of destructor calls when running on Windows, and an invalid pointer error in Linux (after ~20 d'tors calls).

What I can't figure out is why is there a difference between the two? why don't I get an infinite loop with `new char` or crash?

Comment: Because undefined behaviour. You can't expect anything in particular from code with this kind of bugs.

Comment: What is defined as `undefined`? the delete[] on a pointer?

Comment: Yes, calling `delete[]` on something not allocated with `new[]`.

Comment: I was not aware this is undefined, thank you

Comment: It is known that MSVC just *happens* to generate exactly the same code for `delete` and `delete[]` with built in types like `char`. For types with a destructor, the code is very different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shall use `delete[]` with and only with a pointer which was allocated using `new[]`;

**The problem**

In your first code snippet:

- With the statement `char* str = new char;` you get a pointer to a single char.  So the type from new matches the `char*`.
- But your `delete[]` expects a pointer to an array of char, so you get undefined behavior (UB) when you delete something that is not an array

The second code snippet has exactly the same problem.  UB is undefined and can give strange and unexplainable results.

**How to solve it ?**

Either use a single element delete for a single element allocation:

```
  Foo* foo = new Foo;
  delete foo;
```

Or use an array delete for an array allocation:

```
  Foo* foo = new Foo[1];
  delete[] foo;
```

Or better:  get rid of any new/delete you're tempted to use and use vectors instead of arrays.

Comment: @ZivS use delete instead of delete[]

Answer (score 2):

To make this short,  calling `delete[]` for a pointer that was not allocated with `new[]` and is not `null` is always ***undefined***

I quote from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete):

> *Called by delete[]-expressions to deallocate storage previously allocated for an array of objects. The behavior of the standard
>   library implementation of this function **is undefined** unless ptr is
>   a null pointer or is a pointer previously obtained from the standard
>   library implementation of operator new or operator
>   new[](size_t, std::nothrow_t).*